# How to force conversion of glyphs to embedded vector paths in Inkscape

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, inkscape, glyph, svg-font

I have created an SVG document with Inkscape.  It contains text in a non-standard font.  The `svg` xml references the font.  So, the vector has a dependency on the font being available on the users machine (or by using web fonts in a web scenario).  I want to remove this dependency.  I know how to do it manually, but it would be time consuming.

**Does Inkscape provide a way to include the required glyphs as pure vectors instead of referencing the font?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can transform all glyphs to vectors by selecting them and using the `object to path` function (`Path`->`Object to Path`).

Comment: +1, but both of you guys answered an hour ago.  Who was first?

Comment: @smartcaveman: You can hover the mouse over the "answered 1 hour ago sign" to see the exact time the answer was given.

Comment: For inkscape 0.92 if the symbols are really treated as "glyphs" (shared), then a [copy/paste to another file is needed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1674033).

Answer (score 3):

Select the text(s) you want to convert to paths, then select "Path > Object to Path".

If the font license allows it you could also use it as a webfont, by adding some css to the svg file, see [this example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/fonts/webfonts_in_svg.svg). Inkscape doesn't support webfonts AFAIK, but for editing I guess it might still work if you have the same font installed on your system.

Comment: +1, but both of you guys answered an hour ago.  Who was first?

Comment: I'd recommend using a subsetted webfont over converting text to shapes. Keeping text as text is better for accessibility (also for search engine indexing and for possibly changing the text in the future). It depends on how much text you have though, for a logo it might not matter much.